# Python script: Character 1 equal to character n

Tags: python

I am new to python and need some help. I am supposed to write a script that will read words from a keyboard until the word 999 is entered. For each word except 999, report whether the word is valid or invalid. The word is valid if its first character is equal to its last character. I cannot figure out what I am doing incorrect. Can someone help?

Thanks

`enter code here`

```
def main():
  newChance = True
  while newChance == True:
      try:
          Code = raw_input("Enter a word.")
      except ValueError:
           print("You need to use letters only!")
           try:
                 startOver = int(input("To start over, enter 0. To exit enter 999."))
           except:
                 print("Goodbye...")
                 newChance = False
           else:
                 if startOVer == 0:
                        newChance = True
                 else:
                        print("Goodbye...")
                        newChance = False
                        str1 = Code
                        if str1.startswith('"') and str1.endswith('"'):
                                print ("Your word is valid.")
                 else:
                                print ("Your word is invalid.")
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the wall you have run into and what the program is currently doing for you? (because it may be doing something slightly different for me/ on my system)

Comment: Is having a double quote the condition for the entered text being a valid word? I would suggest you try the re (regular expression) module to check if the entered text contains only characters ([a-zA-Z]). May be the regex you're looking for a valid word is ^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*\1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to comment about your code. First is your usage of TRY/EXCEPT blocks.

These are used for error handling. Which you have used correctly in:

```
  try:
      Code = raw_input("Enter a word.")
  except ValueError:
```

The problem here is that you are locating your primary logic inside your error handling. This means that if the user initially inputted a number correctly, it'll never actually reach your logic.

That being said, that error catching isn't working on my system. You may want to approach it instead as an IF/ELSE and check if it's a digit using `Code.isdigit()`;

It would also be wise to add validation on your exit logic.

In the end, it should probably look something like this:

```
newChance = True
while newChance == True:
    Code = raw_input("Enter a number.")
    if Code.isdigit():
        if Code[0] == Code[-1]:
          print ("Your word is valid.")
        else:
          print ("Your word is invalid.")

        startOverValid = False
        while not(startOverValid):
          startOver = int(input("To start over, enter 0. To exit enter 999."))
          if startOver == 999:
            print("Goodbye...")
            newChance = False
            startOverValid = True
          if startOver == 0:
            startOverValid = True
    else:
        print("You need to use letters only!")
```

Key points to note is the use of `if Code[0] == Code[-1]:`. Since our raw_input is a string, we can check the indexes of both of the first and last character and ensure they are matching.

We move on to handling a restart or exit. Since we've placed ourselves in a loop, we only need to test for our 2 valid looping breaking conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method:

```
def main():
  newChance = True
  while newChance:
      Code = input("Enter a word.")
      if Code.isdigit():
           print("You need to use letters only!")
           try:
                 startOver = int(input("To start over, enter 0. To exit enter 999."))
           except:
                 print("Goodbye...")
                 newChance = False
           else:
                 if startOver == 0:
                        newChance = True
                 else:
                        print("Goodbye...")
                        newChance = False
                        break
      str1 = Code
      if str1[0]==str1[-1]:
          print ("Your word is valid.")
      else:
         print ("Your word is invalid.")
```

So basically instead of the first try-except, we do an if statement, because the try-except will never raise, and all so a misspelling of `startOver` being `startOVer`, has been fixed, and indentation has been fixed, and added a `break`, a lot of small changes can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to check if the word is valid or not using lambda function is the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

valid = lambda x: True if x[0] == x[len(x) - 1] else False

for i in range(0,998):
    ask = input("Please enter word: ")

    print("# Word is valid!") if valid(ask) is True else print("# Word is invalid!")
```

Sample Results from the script:

```
>>> 
======================= RESTART: D:/Python/checker.py =======================
Please enter word: tester
# Word is invalid!
Please enter word: testing
# Word is invalid!
Please enter word: test
# Word is valid!
Please enter word:
```